# Joining common items in python lists

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['a','d']
list2 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
```

I want to either append list1 or create a new list that results in:

```
[('a', '1'), ('d', '4')]
```

I've tried using index with no luck.

Comment: FYI: you aquired a downvote/downvotes because you did not present what you have tried and *how* it did not work.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  ... and its a dupe, I cant find it. Something along the lines of "select elemnents from list by element in other list" - normally its a list and a list of indexes wanted, in this case its slightly different though similar. This "problem" could be soved with a simple `for el in list2:` and append it to a result list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this simply using a list comprehension:

```
list3 = [t for t in list2 if t[0] in list1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as desired.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter the elements that interest you:

```
list1 = ['a','d']
list2 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]

# operating on a set makes the lookups O(1) which is faster then O(n) for lists.
# List with few elements (4-5) are still better then a set() due to the overhead
# a set introduces
whatIwant = set(list1)

# python 2.x filter returns a list directly
list3 = filter(lambda x: x[0] in whatIwant,list2) 


print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[('a', '1'), ('d', '4')]
```

`filter(function, iterable)` operates on any `iterable` and applies the function on each element and to determine if the element of the iterable should be in the output (`function(item) == True`) or not (`function(item) == False` )

---

For python3: `filter(...)` will return an iterator, so you need to stuff the result into a `list(...)` to get a list returned.

Comment: Note that you are creating `set(list1)` as many times as your lambda function is called. I recommend to compute it once, before filtering.

Comment: If your using python3, you would need to wrap `list()`, since `filter()` gives back a iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary from your key, value list `list2`.

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'd']
>>> list2 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
>>> d2 = dict(list2)
```

The dict looks like this:

```
>>> d2
{'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'b': '2'}
>>> d2['c']
'3'
```

Get the values for the keys in `list1`.

```
>>> [(k, d2[k]) for k in list1]
[('a', '1'), ('d', '4')]
```

Also, you might prefer numeric data instead of numbers encoded as strings. In this case, create the dictionary with

```
>>> d2 = dict((k, int(v)) for k,v in list2)
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: This answer is same as of [Sunitha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001238/8278951).

Comment: @RahulGoswami so what? I hit "post" a few seonds later and explained what's going on. What makes this answer "not useful" to you?

Comment: Sorry, but when I did the comment, the answer was exactly as same as the one. I guess you added the explanation in further edits. I just upvoted this. Cheers! :)

Comment: @RahulGoswami no problem, glad we could help :)

Comment: It does have a couple of limitations, i.e. no duplicates keys in `list2` and that all things in `list1` exist in `list2`, but it is unclear if this is material to the OP.

Comment: @AChampion sure, when OPs give no additional information you kind of have to assume that their data is well behaved such that no ambiguities can arise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution

```
list1 = ['a','d'] 
list2 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
my_set = set(list1)
new_list = [(x, y) for x, y in list2 if x in my_set]
```

Comment: Also it would be better to put `set(list1)` outside the loop, so you don't create a new set on each iteration.

Comment: @RoadRunner Nice observation! I will edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AChampion true, the version the answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the list `list2` into a dict, it would be easier for you do what you want

```
>>> list1 = ['a','d']; list2 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')] 
>>> dict2 = dict(list2)
>>> list3 = [(e, dict2[e]) for e in list1]
>>> 
>>> list3
[('a', '1'), ('d', '4')]
```